# React typescript pass props not declared in the interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hello i'm just getting started with typescript and react!

I have this simple button component

```
import React from 'react'
interface Props{
    className?:string,
    onClick:()=> void,
    children: React.ReactNode
}
export const Button:React.FC<Props> = ({onClick = ()=>1,children,className = "",...rest}) =>{
return(
        <button onClick={onClick} className={"r-button cursor-p br " + className} {...rest}>
            {children}
        </button>)
}
```

and it works fine but if i try to add an attribute to the component that i use only for stylind something like this

```
<Button loading="true" onClick={()=>console.log("yoohoi")}>Click me!</Button>
```

I get this error regardin the loading attribute

```
Type '{ children: (Element | ReactNode)[]; className: string; onClick: () => Promise<void>; loading: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'loading' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

So my question is how do i handle passing attributes that i use only for styling purposes without having to declare them in the props interface? i Thought that ...rest would do the job :/

Comment: You can use data-* attributes for this. However, why not to use just custom class, like `classNanme='loading'`?

Comment: :O seems like he likes it, why does the data-loading works ?

Comment: because data attributes was designed exactly for this purpose, and luckily React respects this), see the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

- Either data-* attribute (because data attributes was designed as custom attributes and [React allows them](https://ru.reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/08/dom-attributes-in-react-16.html))
- Or pass className which will style the element when loading

Comment: Oh i understand! Thanks for the explanation, i could use a class for sure but i wanted to see how to allow the use of attributes cuz this component might be used by other people who could use an attribute for styling stuff instead of just classes :)

Comment: Sure!I'll accept the answer soon (have to wait 4 minutes for some reason)

Answer (score 0):

Adding an additional solution that could help others.
You could also extend ComponentProps which can be used to pass in any additional pros.

```
interface Props extends ComponentProps<any> {
    className?:string,
    onClick:()=> void,
    children: React.ReactNode
}
```

and spread the entire props to your child component, Make sure that props are sent ahead of those your want to override.

```
export const Button:React.FC<Props> = ({props: Props) => { 
return(
   <button {...props} className={"r-button cursor-p br " + props.className} >
       {children}
   </button>) 
}
```